# Jboss standalone vs domain mode - multiple nodes and remote jms

Tags: jboss, jms

What is a preferred solution in case when EAP runs in 2-3 nodes and we want to use shared jms queues there?
Is standalone HA mode with shared queue-s enough, or better use domain mode there?

Comment: What is a "shared JMS queue"? Are you talking about clustering the embedded JMS brokers in EAP or something else?

Comment: One version is, when embedded ActiveMQ handles same remote jms queues in all nodes.

Comment: I don't understand. "One version is" what?

Comment: One possible solution. Based on current study, distributed queue could be the best solution for us. In that case, domain mode wont be relevant.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "distributed queue"?

Comment: There is a standalone-full-ha.xml possibility, the servers are in same network will automatically using UDP protocol and share messages across server instances. Based on RH support pages.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way would be to run Artemis by itself and connect to it. You can also define connectors to a specific node that would host the JMS broker.
HA is there to do what it says : HA, not for sharing destinations.